Is It True that covariance of powers of norms is nonnegative?
I want to show that if $\mathbf{x}\sim N(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I}_d)$, then $\operatorname{cov}(\|\mathbf{x}\|^a, \|\mathbf{x}\|^b)\geq 0$ for any $a, b\geq 0$. I have a hunch that it is true, since increasing $\|\mathbf{x}\|^a$ involves increasing $\|\mathbf{x}\|$, which increases $\|\mathbf{x}\|^b$, and vice versa. However, I cannot seem to formally prove it. Any suggestions on where to start? There aren't a lot of "integral" or direct formulas for covariance except
$$\operatorname{cov}(\|\mathbf{x}\|^a, \|\mathbf{x}\|^b)=\mathbb{E}[\|\mathbf{x}\|^{a+b}]-\mathbb{E}[\|\mathbf{x}\|^a]\mathbb{E}[\|\mathbf{x}\|^b],$$
which would involve nasty integrals. Any hints would be great.

If $f$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$ then for $a,b,c\geq 0$ we have
$$f(a+b+c)-f(b+c)\geq f(a+c)-f(c)$$ since $f'(a+b+c)\geq f'(a+c)$ (the derivative of a convex function is non decreasing). It is notorious that $\log \Gamma(x)$ is a convex function. Now observe that $Y=\|X\|^2/2 $ is Gamma distributed with shape parameter $c=d/2$ when $X\sim N(0,I_d).$ Therefore the covariance of $Y^a$ and $Y^b$ is $$C=\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(c)}-\frac{\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(c)}\times \frac{\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(c)}$$ Saying that $C$ is non negative is equivalent to saying that $$f(a+b+c)-f(b+c)- f(a+c)+f(c)\geq 0$$ with $f=\log \Gamma.$
